# python anywhere Error running WSGI application no module named "Wasp"

Tags: pythonanywhere

im new to pythonanywhere

im getting this error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Wasp'

My WSGI Settings

```
path = '/home/waspdeco/waspdeco/Wasp'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Wasp.settings'
```

and my files directory for settings.py

/home/waspdeco/waspdeco/Wasp

i dont know what i am doing wrong any help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `path` should be `/home/waspdeco/waspdeco`

Take a look at the Django section of  https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/